# Can JSCH get messages quickly enough from remote server

Tags: java, jsch, fix-protocol

I want to write a java tool to monitor some FIX log. The idea is using SSH to logon remote server, then getting the output of command "tail -f xxx" to my PC, rest is some log analysis work. 
  When I tested with JSCH, whatever I read information from a bufferReader or directly from a InputStream, I found the output was delay, much slower than the result of running "tail -f xxx" in putty.
  Is there something missing in my codes? Or it is not a good way to continuously get log info     with JSCH?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause, guys.
I used "tail -f xxx | grep zzz", such command. Because 'grep' uses buffering, thus I got some output delay. I've moved the filtering on my local side, the testing result is much better.

Comment: If your version supports it (GNU grep does), using `grep --line-buffered` can avoid this problem (at the cost of some extra CPU load).